# hash object clarification in sas data step

Tags: hash, sas

I am learning hash object in **sas** and I would like to track the difference between sales performance and target. I've attribute id, qtrnum and amt the sales achieved.

the sales data set is like following:

```
data contrib;
    input id $ qtrnum $ amt;
    datalines;
a001 atr1 12
a001 atr2 13
a002 atr1 11
a002 atr2 18
;
run;
```

and the target is in hash object:

```
data difference (drop = amt2);
    length amt2 8;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash goal();
        goal.definekey("Qtrnum");
        goal.definedata("Amt2");
        goal.definedone();
        call missing(qtrnum, amt2);
        goal.add(key:'atr1', data:9);
        goal.add(key:'atr2', data:13);
    end;
    set contrib;
    goal.find();
    diff = amt - amt2;
run;
```

while it gives error:

> ERROR: Variable qtrnum has been defined as both character and numeric.

Please delight me. Many thanks.

Comment: hint: call missing :)

Comment: for me this question is fine, dunno why someone downvoted you, anyway I upvoted to return to 0. cheers.

Comment: may i have more hints? it seems ok after i added the line length qtrnum $4.;

Answer (score 3):

SAS will create the variable the first time that it is referenced.  In your program the first reference to QTRNUM is in this line.

```
  call missing(qtrnum, amt2);
```

SAS cannot tell from that whether QTRNUM is numeric or character so it made it a numeric.

**You don't really need that line so why not just remove it.**

One way to insure variables are defined first is include a line like this at the top of the data step.

```
if 0 then set contrib;
```

Since 0 is false the SET statement is never executed, but during the compilation of the data step SAS will define all of the variables in CONTRIB.

Comment: Why include the `if 0 then...` statement when you can just move the hash table definition underneath the set statement?

Comment: Usually the table being loaded into the hash is a different table than the one that the data step is processing.

Comment: And if they are using the field for the key, then the types will be the same.  If they're not, the source data should be changed.

Comment: hi tom, may i have sample code to load table into hash?

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly define the Qtrnum variable too.

```
length Qtrnum $8;
```

or may look like:

```
data difference (drop = amt2);
length amt2 8 Qtrnum$8;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash goal();
    goal.definekey("Qtrnum");
    goal.definedata("Amt2");
    goal.definedone();
    call missing(qtrnum, amt2);
    goal.add(key:'atr1', data:9);
    goal.add(key:'atr2', data:13);
end;
set contrib;
goal.find();
diff = amt - amt2;
run;
```